# SIGSEGV in mini-exceptions.c:1953

Tags: mono

I am trying to run a simple Xamarin.Mac application using a custom-built, 64-bit copy of Mono. The program intermittently crashes soon after launch (after assemblies have been loaded), complaining of following problem:

`` Assertion at mini-exceptions.c:1953, condition `gaddr == tls->stack_ovf_guard_base' not met ``

[Here is my full crash log.](https://gist.github.com/wjk/1ddaef0fc0b6ed4f5555)

Whenever the app does not crash, it runs perfectly normally. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, the problem was due to the usage of the SGen garbage collector under 64-bit mode. There are apparently still some bugs in there.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you found a bug in the mono runtime, I think it has to do with the JIT compiler. I believe that error is indicating that some sort of stack corruption occurred while running native code. I would report the error to the mono developers - http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs.

It seems that 64-bit mac support has some limitations and doesn't seem to be 100% supported - http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX#32_and_64_bit_support:

> The 64 bit support has a few limitations today which is why we have
>   not entirely switched to it:   Our Windows.Forms implementation uses
>   Carbon, and as such, it would not work with a 64-bit Mono.
>   MonoDevelop uses Carbon for its menu integration so it would not run
>   on a 64-bit VM.   MonoMac bindings have not been ported to 64 bits.

Comment: The reason why I didn’t heed those warnings is that I don’t use Windows.Forms and I’m using Xamarin’s commercial version of the MonoMac DLL. I guess I’ll have to report it; I just don’t know how to isolate the problem without requiring the Xamarin team to replicate my entire setup.

Comment: Any chance you can try the 32-bit version? It might be better supported or have fewer bugs.

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, it looks like it has something to do with threads and thread-local-storage, though I don't know if that's something that the runtime is doing for its own internal purposes or if its on the behalf of the code you were running. Perhaps you could try to reproduce with a simpler program that uses TLS?

Comment: I cannot use the 32-bit version because I am making an app to submit to the Mac App Store, which requires that I build 64-bit. I have no clue how to write a C# program that uses Mono TLS. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: It's part of .Net's threading support - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx - mono should support it all the same. That said, I can't guarantee that this is what's wrong.

Comment: In the name of debugging the runtime, could you try 32-bit anyway?

Comment: I did, and it works under 32-bit. However, I then rebuilt Mono from source in 64-bit mode, _with the SGen garbage collector disabled_. Then it worked; apparently, SGen still has some bugs in 64-bit mode. Using the older Boehm garbage collector works a lot better.

Comment: Ah, so there you go. You should create your own post with that information and mark it as the answer.